# Connection to VPN?

Tags: connection, debian, vpn

Can anyone help me figure out how should I configure this VPN connection, like what should I use an any help on the configuration files?

[image]

Extra information: I'm inside a LAN network and I need to connect a single pc/server in that VPN server

Comment: most VPN servers provide automatically generated ovpn/conf files. If you can acquire one of those, you can directly establish vpn connections like: vpn_client -f conf_file. In the case of openvpn this looks like: '/path/to/openvpn -f /path/to/conf/file'

Comment: Does the "Port" line say `1701`, `4500` or `10000`?

Comment: @grawity i guess the "port" line has been obfuscated so that you (and me) don't know what "port" has been set to :-)

Comment: @umlaeute: Which is why I'm asking.